# self.editing vs. self.tableView.editing and setEditing confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction, setediting

After presenting a modal view on my UITableView controller when editing is on, I found that the values of `self.editing` and `self.tableView.editing` are different when the controller is dismissed (`self.editing` was still on but `self.tableView.editing` had gone off and the tableView was in a strange state).

To correct this, I did  `[self setEditing:NO animated:YES]` when presenting the modal view.

I've discovered that these two lines do not do the same thing:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
[self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

**My questions are:**

**(1)** why is there a difference in those commands and

**(2)** how can the state of `self.editing` and `self.tableView.editing` be different?

Comment: Isn't *self.editing* related to viewcontroller and other to tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation

```
self.editing
```

A Boolean value indicating whether the viewController currently allows the user to edit the view contents

```
self.tableView.editing
```

A Boolean value that determines whether the table view is in editing mode.

I think you can understand by the definition it self, viewController editing refers to if the viewController allows editing.

Comment: Thank you, Gihan, that cleared it up.  I had confused the two, but they are only loosely related. In a tableView controller.  [self setEditing:] needs to call super and the tableView's setEditing: method.